# DB-Toolkit Plugin - on save redirects to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and returns only a 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

So I aquired a project that is using DB-Toolkit to make a section of the site but the section hadn't been updated in a while ( as in added new content too ) but recently I went to add new content to it and when I click save on the modal window in DB-Toolkit it just redirects me to admin-ajax.php and returns only 0. I looked around in the admin-ajax.php for a die('0') and well theres a lot of them.

I have never used this plugin before and since this is now breaking the production site I need to fix it asap but after a day of trying on my own I have gotten no where..

any ideas / help is appreciated.

the version of wordpress I'm using is 3.2.1 and the version of the db-toolkit plugin is 0.2.6.9 ( i know this is old but when I updated it got even worse, loss of Applications as well as interfaces and it fails to import the backups I have from db-toolkit. so until I fix this issue I don't want to update )

the site was working about 3 weeks ago according to the db records ( last inserted record to the table being used by db-toolkit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another Plugin removed the dt_start action on the admin and front end, once I just disabled it on the front end everything was fine.